# Excel vba MsgBox to display message when duplicate is found

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to remove duplicates from a table in Excel, I have a piece of code that removes duplicates without any problem, I am wondering if I could make it prompt a message box when a duplicate is found saying something along the lines "This entry is a duplicate entry" Any suggestions? This Is what I got so far:

```
Sub AccessTransfer()
    Range("A1:F1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Value = "Oven"

    Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
    Call GoDupe
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub



Sub GoDupe()

    Cells.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlNo
    Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: You would need to loop to identify the dupes and write them to a string. Using what you have, there is no way to identify which are actually dupes and which are unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than looping through, identifying and prompting for each duplicate, you could simply highlight all duplicates and prompt the user once.
Your `GoDupe()` sub could look something like this:

```
Sub GoDupe()

Cells.FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues
With Cells.FormatConditions(Cells.FormatConditions.Count)
    .DupeUnique = xlDuplicate
    .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End With
If MsgBox("Red highlighted cells are duplicated. OK to remove duplicates?", vbOKCancel) = vbOK Then
    Cells.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlNo
    Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
End If
Cells.FormatConditions(Cells.FormatConditions.Count).Delete
```

End Sub

Comment: Just one thing, I only want the first column(A column) to be highlighted and deleted for duplicates, all other columns have duplicate values sometimes and that is ok, is there to make that work?

Comment: You should then call the `RemoveDuplicates` function from a specific range, rather than simply `Cells`. E.g. `Range("$A:$A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlNo`